# updating one row with current timestamp based on it's id

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
id | date    | date2
3  |2019-1-6| NULL
2  |2019-1-5| NULL
1  |2019-1-2| NULL
```

I want my query to update `date2` only for the newest id:

```
id | date    | date2
3  |2019-1-6 | 2019-1-7
2  |2019-1-5 | NULL
1  |2019-1-2 | NULL
```

I tried this but it won't let me use select clause in where while using an update query.

```
update table set data2=current_timestamp where id=(select max(id) from table)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define in which order the records are being updated and stop after the first one:

```
update your_table 
set data2 = current_timestamp 
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Shoudln't that be `current_timestamp()` or does that function work without the `()`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks mate

Comment: @RiggsFolly: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp

Comment: Juergen Thank you.